# virtual host creation in windows8

Tags: virtualhost

I am trying to save the hosts file in `c://windows/system32/drivers/etc` and it always asks me the type in which the file has to be saved and if I select hosts it says access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run "notepad" with administrator permissions and in this window open hosts file. Then you should be able to save it.